# How to merge two methods for react and google realtime database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

When i select the first one it shows me the correct results but when i select the second one it loses the first value. I want to merge both. I am using two separate dropdowns at the moment.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSort(true);
    fireDb
      .child("projects")
      .orderByChild("projectmanager")
      .equalTo(`${e.target.value}`)
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        let sortedData = [];
        snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
          sortedData.push(snap.val());
        });
        setSortedData(sortedData);
      });
  };


const handleChangeOne = (e) => {
    setSort(true);
    fireDb
      .child("projects")
      .orderByChild(`${e.target.value}`)
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        let sortedData = [];
        snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
          sortedData.push(snap.val());
        });
        setSortedData(sortedData);
      });
  };
```

Comment: At first glance this code looks fine. Did you already set a breakpoint in the second handler and run in a debugger to see whether `e.target.value` matches what you expect?

Comment: Yes the code works fine but i want to merge both :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to merge these queries, so if you want the results of both queries to show, you'll have to execute both queries and put the results in the same array:

```
fireDb
  .child("projects")
  .orderByChild("projectmanager")
  .equalTo(`${e.target.value}`)
  .on("value", (snapshot) => {
    // Done with first query, add the results to a new array
    const sortedData = [];
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      sortedData.push(snap.val());
    });
    // Done with first query, so fire the second query
    fireDb
      .child("projects")
      .orderByChild(`${e.target.value}`)
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        // Add the results of the second query to the same array
        snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
          sortedData.push(snap.val());
        });
        // Done with second query, so show the data in the UI
        setSortedData(sortedData);
      });
  });
```

Comment: I tried your code and getting errors, I adjusted and managed to remove the errors with code below but it is still not working.

Comment: setSort(true);
    fireDb
    .child("projects")
    .orderByChild("projectmanager")
    .equalTo(`${e.target.value}`)
    .on("value", (snapshot) => {
      const sortedData = [];
      snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
        sortedData.push(snap.val());
      });
    })
    fireDb
      .child("projects")
      .orderByChild("invoiceeta")
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
          sortedData.push(snap.val());
        });
        setSortedData(sortedData);
      });
  };

Comment: Your second `on` is still **outside** of the callback of the first `on`, so it doesn't do the same as my code does. Does it make sense why you need to **nest** the calls as I do in my answer?

Comment: When i put it inside i get an error that is why i put it outside

Comment: Unnesting it won't work. What is the error you get when nesting it.

Comment: I get the red error because of the brackets not being closed, i can't add a screenshot to show you how it looks

Comment: As far as I can see the blocks in the code in my answer are all OK. Did you try fixing the brackets by counting them and seeing where every block closes? --- You can also edit your question to show what you did based on the code from my answer. Just make sure to lead the original code, and add the updated code as an update, as otherwise things become confusing for future visitors.